# How i can get return value from cordova plugin in Android?

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova

I wrote a Java class that is a part of a cordova plugin, the main code is:

```
public class ClassName extends CordovaPlugin {

  protected void pluginInitialize() {}

  public boolean execute(String action, JSONArray args, CallbackContext callbackContext) throws JSONException {

    if (action.equals("getData")) {
      CallbackContext callback = null;

      Test ts  = new Test();
      String result = ts.TestNow();

      PluginResult pluginResult = new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.OK, result);
      pluginResult.setKeepCallback(true);
      callbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult);

      return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

This is the js code of the plugin:

```
cordova.define("cordova-plugin-NAME.PLUGINNAME", function(require, exports, module) {
module.exports = {
  getdata: function(message, successCallback) {
    cordova.exec(successCallback, null, "ClassName", "getData", [message]);
  }
};
});
```

And this is the js that i use to call plugin function:

```
function myFunc(){
 alert('Function started');
 ClassName.getdata(successCallback, null);
 }

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
    document.getElementById('test').addEventListener('click', myFunc);
});
```

I have two questions:

1) My java class get in output a String result, how I can pass the result to my javascript function ( myfunc() )?

2) I don't understand what is the fucntion of "successCallback", could someone make me one example ?

Comment: Have a look to that, I answered it few days ago and it is quite similar to your request: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36900008/when-calling-a-plugin-method-from-phonegap-app-data-returned-from-native-androi/36988940#comment61723835_36988940

Answer (score 1, accepted):

successCallback in JS is executed when retrieving  callbackContext.sendPluginResult(pluginResult) from JAVA.

The sucessCallback should look like:

```
successCallback:function(event){ 
    .... Do things with the 'event' object received from JAVA
}
```

The "event" object is the object answered from JAVA.